# add_theme_support( $feature='menus' )

Tags: menus, add-theme-support

I want to ask why after I deleted the add_theme_support($feature='menus') in my functions.php there is still menus in my theme activated. why it is still there even if I did not write the add_theme_support for menu. Can anyone explain it? thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for `add_theme_support()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/):

> The following parameters are read only, and should only be used in the context of [current_theme_supports()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_theme_supports):
>
> ...
>
> - `menus`: Use [register_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/) or [register_nav_menus()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menus/) instead.
>
> ...

So your theme shouldn't be using `add_theme_support($feature='menus')` to begin with. Support is automatically added by `register_nav_menu()`. If you don't want menu options for your theme, make sure you're not using `register_nav_menu()` anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. I accidentally fix the problem and that was I not activating my custom theme that is why the code does not effect. Thank you for answering my question.